# Parse Login: "Unfortunately, (App) has stopped."

Tags: android

I am creating an app where the user has to be logged in to use the app. However, the user cannot create an account, I create it for them as not everyone is permitted to use it. I am using Parse for the database. When I start my app the app automatically closes, I am gonna post the logcat and if you can help me come to a solution I would be delighted, also possibly tell me how you spotted where it went wrong?
Thanks. I have pasted the red section of the logcat.

```
12-14 15:16:51.149  16230-16230/lawnswood.lsa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lawnswood.lsa, PID: 16230
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbolts/Task;
            at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:44)
            at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:150)
            at lawnswood.lsa.LSA.onCreate(LSA.java:12)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bolts.Task" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/lawnswood.lsa-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:44)
            at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:150)
            at lawnswood.lsa.LSA.onCreate(LSA.java:12)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bolts.Task
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 15 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Try [this site](http://google.com) and paste your exception name in there.

Comment: @323go exception? I'm new to all this. Sorry if my question was stupid.

Comment: can you post GcmRegistrar.java..?

Comment: @bachu I found the problem, I made a silly mistake. I forgot to compile bolts-android-1.1.4.jar in my build.gradle file. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 5):

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}

please write above code in proguard-project.txt in eclipse project.