# Error in android studio logcat java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-manifest

I am new android developer and I faced problem after I update android studio v 1.3.2 for windows 7

I get this problem when I declare android name in the manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.liveupdate" > 
<application
        **android:name=".LiveUpdateApplication"**
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

in java LiveUpdateApplication I initialize Parse

```
public class LiveUpdateApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this, "", "");// I write my key here 

    }
}
```

the error in logcat is : -

```
09-02 15:39:21.347  16301-16301/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.liveupdate, PID: 16301
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbolts/Task;
            at com.parse.ParseInstallation.hasCurrentInstallationAsync(ParseInstallation.java:88)
            at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:96)
            at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:219)
            at com.example.user.liveupdate.LiveUpdateApplication.onCreate(LiveUpdateApplication.java:17)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bolts.Task" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.liveupdate-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.parse.ParseInstallation.hasCurrentInstallationAsync(ParseInstallation.java:88)
            at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:96)
            at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:219)
            at com.example.user.liveupdate.LiveUpdateApplication.onCreate(LiveUpdateApplication.java:17)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bolts.Task
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 16 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
09-02 15:39:23.237  16301-16301/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 16301 SIG: 9
```

I tried many solutions but it doesn't work with me 
so I hope you could help me

thank you in advance

Comment: What's `bolts.Task`? Try to clear/Rebuild project

Comment: I already clear and rebuild the project and i get the same problem

Comment: Paste the bolts.task class then

Comment: Problem is in your library or the dependency.Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470779/parse-login-unfortunately-app-has-stopped

Comment: thank you so much I forget to add bolts as a library so now my problem is solved , thank you